# SFML rendertexture not returning texture

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm having an issue getting an sfml rendertexture to return it's texture properly I believe i've narrowed it down to this bit of code. I believe it has something to do with the way i'm trying to copy the texture in the rendertexture into a map of textures.

renderedchunks will be private i just have it public for testing out the function quick.

Here's the header file

```
#ifndef TILE_MAP_H
#define TILE_MAP_H
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <map>
#include "Chunk.h"
//Class designed to manipulate chunks
//


class Tile_Map
{
public:
    Tile_Map();
    void RenderChunk(Texture_Manager&, int x, int y);
    void CreateChunk(int x, int y); //Eventually will create based on biomes
    std::map<int, std::map<int, sf::Texture> > renderedchunks;



protected:
private:



    std::map<int, std::map<int, Chunk> > chunkmap; //Used to store all created chunks



};
```

Here's the cpp file

```
#include "Tile_Map.h"

Tile_Map::Tile_Map()
{
//ctor
}

void Tile_Map::CreateChunk(int x, int y)
{

chunkmap[x][y];
Chunk& chunk = chunkmap[x][y];
chunk.SetBiome("grass");
}

void Tile_Map::RenderChunk(Texture_Manager& tempmanager, int x, int y)
{
sf::RectangleShape drawable[8][8];
sf::RenderTexture drawingtexture;
Chunk& rchunk = chunkmap[x][y];

float renderx = 0;
float rendery = 0;

if(rchunk.GetBiome() == "grass")
{
    for(int it = 0; it < 8; it++)
    {
        for(int it2 = 0; it2 < 8; it2++)
        {
            drawable[it][it2].setTexture(&tempmanager.GetTexture("grass"));
            drawable[it][it2].setPosition(renderx, rendery);
            drawingtexture.draw(drawable[it][it2]);
            std::cout << "x = " << renderx << std::endl;
            renderx += 32;

        }
        renderx = 0;
        std::cout << "y = " << rendery << std::endl;
        rendery += 32;
    }
}
drawingtexture.display();
renderedchunks[x][y] = drawingtexture.getTexture();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you need a copy of sf::Texture ? Each chunk will have a copy of a texture, imagine if it's 1024x1024 px picture, and it's size is 1 mb, 50*50 will equal to 2500 mb of ram, so the best thing for you, will be to store the pointer to the texture, so you could have one original texture and all other will point to it's address in memory and use the original texture

Comment: my chunk class doesn't have a texture stored. the tile_map class is responsible for creating a texture for it and storing it. only the chunks around the player are going to be rendered. then released from memory when not able to be seen anymore.

Comment: Also not every chunk is going to look the same they will eventually all have specific tiles based on their biome and the surrounding chunk's biomes

Comment: if you have something like a resource manager, then you can just select a specific chunk textures, it's not a problem, the main idea, is that your original texture will be in that resource manager and all other will be just references, that do reference on that original texture

Comment: I do have a resource manager that returns a reference to a 32*32 texture. i wanted to build the chunk out of 8*8 of these 32*32 textures. Then store it inside my texture manager class.

Comment: Texture* getTexture(string name) { return map[name]; }

Comment: I already have it setup like that in my texture manager class which i have proven to work so the problem is not in that class, it's in this one. The only difference is in the texture manager class i return by reference instead of a pointer

Comment: reference returns original object, it means, that you can modify original object, better return a pointer, it gives a copy and why do you need a matrix or maps ? Why don't you just assign them a position in matrix and make a single map ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with my design method. I'm just trying to figure out why my rendertexure isn't working

Comment: maybe             drawingtexture.draw(drawable[it][it2].getTexture()); ?

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with the rendertexture and local variables. like am i actually making a copy of the texture in rendertexture or just giving an address?

Answer (score 0):

With only the default constructor of your RenderTexture called, you will get

> an empty, invalid render-texture. You must call create to have a valid render-texture.

So call `create` on your RenderTexture, because:

> Before calling this function, the render-texture is in an invalid state, thus it is mandatory to call it before doing anything with the render-texture.

See [the help file for RenderTexture](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1RenderTexture.php).

Comment: I recognized that and fixed it but for some reason it still wasn't working.